# How to set a Django model table finalized so it can't be changed?

Tags: python, sql, django, database-design, django-models

I am learning Django and it's possible that there is an easy answer out there that I couldn't find because I don't know what to search for.

I have a class/table called `NFLteam` that should never change once it is populated with one entry for each team in the NFL.  I made this a DB table so I could have a Foreign Key in another table that points to a specific NFL team.  Right now teams only have one field, a name.  However in the future they will have more.

From `models.py`

```
class NFLteam( models.Model ):
    team_name  = models.CharField( max_length=3, choices=NFL_TEAMS )

    def __unicode__( self ):
        return self.team_name
```

Here is the `NFL_TEAMS` sequence referenced above:

```
NFL_TEAMS = (
    ( 'ARI', 'Arizona Cardinals' ),
    ( 'ATL', 'Atlanta Falcons' ),
    ( 'BAL', 'Baltimore Ravens' ),
    ( 'BUF', 'Buffalo Bills' ),
    ( 'CAR', 'Carolina Panthers' ),
    ( 'CHI', 'Chicago Bears' ),
    ( 'CIN', 'Cincinnati Bengals' ),
    ( 'CLE', 'Cleveland Browns' ),
    ( 'DAL', 'Dallas Cowboys' ),
    ( 'DEN', 'Denver Broncos' ),
    ( 'DET', 'Detroit Lions' ),
    ( 'GB' , 'Green Bay Packers' ),
    ( 'HOU', 'Houston Texans' ),
    ( 'IND', 'Indianapolis Colts' ),
    ( 'JAX', 'Jacksonville Jaguars' ),
    ( 'KC' , 'Kansas City Chiefs' ),
    ( 'MIA', 'Miami Dolphins' ),
    ( 'MIN', 'Minnesota Vikings' ),
    ( 'NE' , 'New England Patriots' ),
    ( 'NO' , 'New Orleans Saints' ),
    ( 'NYG', 'New York Giants' ),
    ( 'NYJ', 'New York Jets' ),
    ( 'OAK', 'Oakland Raiders' ),
    ( 'PHI', 'Philadelphia Eagles' ),
    ( 'PIT', 'Pittsburgh Steelers' ),
    ( 'SD' , 'San Diego Chargers' ),
    ( 'SEA', 'Seattle Seahawks' ),
    ( 'SF' , 'San Francisco 49ers' ),
    ( 'STL', 'Saint Louis Rams' ),
    ( 'TB' , 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers' ),
    ( 'TEN', 'Tennessee Titans' ),
    ( 'WAS', 'Washington Redskins' ),
)
```

Since the `NFLteam` table should never change (or very, very rarely), is there a way that I can make it finalized or immutable, such that the model will refuse to accept updates to it?  Ideally I'd like this to be DB agnostic so that it works the same with SQLite, MySql, etc. (like the Django model definition).

Comment: probably not a bad idea to set `unique=True` for that field as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a flag somewhere like in your settings, then override the save function for that class and just return if that flag is turned on.

```
from django.conf import settings
...
class NFLTeam(models.Model):
...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if settings.NFL_NO_SAVE is True:
             return
```

Comment: This is a great idea.  Would it be appropriate to put it in the application's `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
class NonUpdateAbleModelMixin():
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class NFLteam(models.Model, NonUpdateAbleModelMixin):
    team_name  = models.CharField( max_length=3, choices=NFL_TEAMS )

    def __unicode__( self ):
        return self.team_name
```

Inside the `save` you can use some flag from settings or whatever you want

Comment: Why would you define a new class for this?  What are the benefits?  Sorry I"m quite new to Django/Python

Comment: its more reusable, just add it to any model you need to behave this way. And its hides the implementation from this specific class which is always better